# Will US universities consider the application of a person with a PhD from India/Singapore/Australia for a faculty position in the US?

Tags: phd, professorship, faculty-application

If I have a PhD degree from other English speaking countries like India/Singapore/Australia, can I apply for a faculty position in the US?

Comment: Someone holding a PhD degree would not be a student anymore so I would edit your question to reflect that (it can be replaced with academic or researcher for example).

Comment: You probably need to be competent in English, but don't need a degree from an English speaking country.

Comment: Since I know a variety of professors from those countries who are professors in the US, the answer is Yes.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can apply, there is no requirement to have a PhD from any particular country/countries in the US.

At a research university, you'll be judged primarily on your research record. Tenure track positions are extremely competitive, you can be well qualified and have a great record and not get a job even if you apply for many open positions; you need to be supremely qualified and have an excellent record and also be a good fit for the hiring institution.

It varies a bit by field, but many positions will expect applicants to have postdoctoral research experience, as well.

Comment: It's also worth noting that they'd have to get a work visa for them, presumably, assuming they didn't have one through other means. I suspect someone nabbing a faculty position would qualify as "exceptional" in their field. But the organization still has to do all the paperwork and wait until they're authorized to work so they have to be that much better than the next best applicant to justify it (obviously, for a long term position like faculty, it will be fine for the obviously better candidate, but if they're split, a citizen may pull out ahead).